# Regex matching first part of domain name

Tags: javascript, mysql, regex

I am trying to match regex for the Fully Qualified Domain Name (fqdn) like this:

```
1.test02a-d.test.example.net
2.test02b-d.test.example.net
3.test03a.test.example.net
4.test03b.test.example.net
5.test04-d.test.example.net
6.test05.test.example.net
```

I tried this regex to get the first part of the fqdn:

```
[^.]+
```

**Criteria:**
Here I need to get the list of fqdn that has alphabets 'a' or 'b' immediately after number in first part. As shown in the above example 1,2,3,4 matches this condition. 
**i.e.,** test02a, test02a-d, test 02b and test02b-d

Fqdn 5 and 6 should be ignored as per the above criteria.

How to modify regex for matching this criteria?

**Note:** This should be used as REGEXP in Mysql and hence some direct javascript regexes didn't work. The solution should be applicable for both javascript and mysql.

Comment: I need an idea for Mysql

Comment: Works for me: https://regex101.com/r/hL6aD0/1

Comment: @TomDoodler It matches whole first part of the string. I need to filter out the fqdn as per the criteria. Only 1,2,3,4 should get matched.

Comment: So add hyphen `[^.-]+`.

Comment: What is fqdn? Never heard that

Comment: @TomDoodler Fully Qualified Domain Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL version:

```
^[^.]+[0-9]+[ab](-[^.]+)?[[:>:]]
```

JavaScript version:

```
^[^.]+[0-9]+[ab](-[^.]+)?\b
```

regex101.com doesn't support MySQL flavor regexp, so I only give the [JavaScript version](https://regex101.com/r/jV2qN2/1). test1bw.test.example.net is added as a test string.

`[[:>]]`  is specific to MySQL. For JavaScript, `\b` should be used instead of `[[:>]]`. `[[:>]]` is a Zero-Length Assertion matching at the end of a word (position preceded by but not followed by an ASCII letter, digit, or underscore). `\b` matches at a position that is the start or end of a word.

MySQL doesn't support any shorthand character classes, so `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]` should be used instead of `\d`

Comment: Thanks. Your solution matches fqdn like this "test1bw.test.example.net". After number there should be only one alphabet. There can be hyphen after that alphabet. This should not be matched

Comment: @GaneshBabu Fixed. I suggest you add "test1bw.test.example.net" or some other test strings to your question to make your criteria clearer.

Answer (score 1):

```
[a-z]+[0-9]+[ab](-d){0,1}(.test.example.net)
```

This Regex matches your first four domain names. The "[a-z]+" could also be specified with "(test)"
You can test it on this site: http://regexr.com/

Comment: Thanks.. It works now. How to ignore rest of the domain part. ie., instead of test.example.net, there may be any names

Comment: You can replace the ".test.example.net" in the regex with your domain, or otherwise you can just use `[a-z]+[0-9]+[ab](-d){0,1}(.)+`

Comment: Thanks.. It works fine. But I am getting matched for examples of this form "test01.test90a-d.example.net". As per my case, I should match only first part of the domain name

Comment: `[a-z]+[0-9]+[ab](-d){0,1}[.][^.]+[.][^.]+[.][^.]{2,4}` would work, but is not a beautiful answer.
**Update:** `[a-z]+[0-9]+[ab](-d){0,1}[.][^.]+(.example.net)` this would also work and i think it's better, but i'm not an expert.

Comment: Thanks again.. But still your new solution didn't work.. :(

Comment: Although your updated solution may work, the domain name example.net is not static throughout my site.

Comment: Sorry i don't know any more answers. Good luck finding one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
^[^.]+\d[ab][^.]*
```

It'll match, from the start of a line (`^`) any characters (more than one) not being a dot. Then there must be a digit followed by an `a` or a `b`, Optionally followed by another sequence of characters not being a dot.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/yG5fG0/5).

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-zA-Z]+[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+.*
```

workes for me... try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/pF3mG5/2) matches the whole domain.

```
[a-zA-Z]+[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+[-\w]*
```

matches only the first part of the domain.

Comment: Thanks. But it didn't work for examples of this form "test01.test90a-d.example.net". I need a match for part before first dot.

Comment: I´ll try to fix it

Comment: what about (?<!.)[a-zA-Z]+[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+[-\w]* like here: https://regex101.com/r/pF3mG5/4

Comment: Lookbehind is not supported in javascript

Comment: Sorry, my mistake... this is not applicatable in js... looking for another solution...

Comment: what ybout using a '^' in combination with multiline flag? like ^[a-zA-Z]+[\d]+[a-zA-Z]+[-\w]*

try: https://regex101.com/r/pF3mG5/5